# SQL attribute variant within the same statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Having the following statement gives me 4 columns (location,description,parent,count) depending on the status:

```
SELECT 
    KINCIDENT.location, LOCATIONS.description, 
    LOCHIERARCHY.parent, count(KINCIDENT.incnum)
FROM 
    KINDICENT, LOCATIONS, LOCHIERARCHY
WHERE 
    KINCIDENT.location = LOCATIONS.location 
    and LOCATIONS.location = LOCHIERARCHY.location 
    AND KINCIDENT.status = 'ECCAPR'
GROUP BY 
    KINCIDENT.location, LOCATIONS.description, LOCHIERARCHY.parent 
ORDER BY 
    parent;
```

However, I'd like a 5th column that gives me the count but when KINCIDENT.status='FSAPR' instead. How can I specify which status each count column takes?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  You should also learn to use explicit `join`s:

```
SELECT k.location, l.description, h.parent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN k.status = 'ECCAPR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_ECCAPR,
       SUM(CASE WHEN k.status = 'FSAPR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_FSAPR
FROM KINDICENT k JOIN
     LOCATIONS l
     ON  k.location = l.location JOIN
     LOCHIERARCHY h
     ON l.location =  h.location    
GROUP BY k.location, l.description, h.parent
ORDER BY parent;
```

I also introduced table aliases which generally make queries easier to write and to read.